# snmp v1 Communication Models if i have many errors in the Getrequest message how to represent it using error index?

Tags: networking, snmp, net-snmp

in Network managment systems

### using **SNMP version 1 **

if i am requesting for any object  and am using **GetRequest(..)**

how it will work if many errors happens in the responce message ? 
and how to represent it using error index ? 
please remember that error index is used to identify and specify which Variable has the error i.e one error >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The error-status and error-index fields should indicate the first variable that was unable to be retrieved due the error indicated by error-status. To determine that any of the remaining variables are also unable to be retrieved, the indicated error needs to be corrected (e.g. variable removed from the request, OID corrected, etc.) and the request re-sent. At that point, the error-status and error-index of the response would indicate the next variable with an error (if any).

Comment: Should refer to RFC1157 (and the newer ones) page 20, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1157#page-20 where you can see how GetRequest-PDU is handled. Other PDUs are processed in a similar manner.